# How do I test for a player at specific coordinates?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

If I do:

```
/testfor @p[x=,y=,z=,r=]
```

It says:

> The entity UUID is in an invalid format.

Answer (score 8):

You're scanning for the nearest player, your should scan for all the players.

### Solution

```
/testfor @a[x=X,y=Y,z=Z,r=R]
```

Where:

- **X** the x location
- **Y** the y location
- **Z** the z location
- **R** the radius

For example:

```
/testfor @a[x=64,y=10,z=64,r=5]
```

(Search for players on coordinates 64,64 at height 10, with a radius of 5 blocks)

### Variables

Specify the location:

- **@p**   nearest player
- **@r**   random player
- **@a**   all players
- **@e**   all entities

Specify the values:

- **x**, **y**, **z**  coordinate
- **r**, **rm**    radius (max, min)
- **m**    game mode
- **c**    count
- **l**, **lm**    experience level (max, min)
- **score_name**   max score
- **score_name_min**   min score
- **team** team name
- **name** entity name
- **dx**, **dy**, **dz**   volume dimensions
- **rx**, **rxm**  vertical rotation (max, min)
- **ry**, **rym**  horizontal rotation (max, min)
- **type** entity type

### Examples:

To test if Alice is online:

```
testfor Alice
```

To count the number of players in survival mode within a 3-block radius of (0,64,0):

```
testfor @a[0,64,0,3,m=0]
```

To count the number of players currently flying:

```
testfor @a {abilities:{flying:1b}}
```

To count the number of zombies within a 20-block radius of (0,64,0):

```
testfor @e[0,64,0,20,type=Zombie]
```

[Source](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#testfor)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. He wants to detect himself.

Comment: His title states that he wants to test for **a player** at specific coordinates, I cannot find where he states that he wants to find himself.

Comment: Isn't he himself a player?

Comment: Correct, He is a player as well. The solution I propose (which scans all players) will include him.

Comment: Sure, but his original intention should be just scanning himself. And there's no problem in his `@p`. You can't just twist his original intention. Well, my opinion.

Comment: @ArceusMaster0493 If the original intention is scanning himself at coordinates (so checking if he's near coordinates), the command should be: `testfor @a[64,64,10,5,name=playername]`. I'm not _twisting_ his original intention, I'm just answering his question which states: `How do I test for a player at specific coordinates?`, which not specifies himself.

Comment: I thought you can do `@p` in `testfor`.

Comment: @ArceusMaster0493 That is correct, you can use `/testfor @p[r=2]` to search around the player in a radius of 2 [source](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Tutorials/Command_Block#As_a_replacement_for_pressure_plates)

Comment: Was this answer true in 2014? Now it's definitely not.

Answer (score 7):

In newer versions of minecraft you can use something like this:

```
/execute as @a[x=100,y=100,z=100,dx=0,dy=0,dz=0] at @s run <command>
```

You need to specify delta values for this to work. The coordinates defined with `x y z` are one corner of the specified area, the delta values `dx dy dz` define how many blocks the second corner is away from the first corner.

You can also use this command:

```
/execute positioned 100 100 100 as @a[distance=..1] at @s run <command>
```

This will execute your command as all players who are within a 1 block radius from the coordinates `100 100 100`.

Comment: I tried the first command in chat, it worked fine. However, when I tried the exact same command in a command block, nothing happened. Strange.

Comment: @Diriector_Doc what exact command did you try to run? The first command should in most cases work the same in a command block as in chat.

Comment: Never mind. I got it to work. Even though it was a repeating command block that was always active, I needed to provide a block update. Then it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that the invalid UUID doesn't always mean that the format is wrong, as I've gotten the error a lot when the format was correct, but no entity was detected.  Make sure you are in the area you've specified, and then retry your command.

Answer (score 0):

You would use the `testfor` command like so:

```
/testfor @a[x=-682,y=4,z=-188,dx=0]
```

Answer (score -4):

You put @p[x,y,z,r] this considers the whole section as the identification of the player try @p [x,y,z,r].