# How to use /testfor command on a specific location 1.9

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm making a custom map and I needed some help from you guys! I'm trying to use the `/testfor` command in 1.9 and here's what I've tried:

```
/testfor @a[-47,10,-37,1]

/testfor @p[-47,10,-37,0]

/testfor @p[-47,10,-37]

/testfor @p[x=-47,y=10,z=-37,r=1]
```

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: First and last command should work fine (and second if you're exactly on that spot). Are you sure that those are the correct coordinates?

Answer (score 1):

## Note: This is a duplicate of: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/198417/153355

However, here's the answer:

You're scanning for the nearest player, your should scan for all the players.

### Solution

```
/testfor @a[x=X,y=Y,z=Z,r=R]
```

Where:

- **X** the x location
- **Y** the y location
- **Z** the z location
- **R** the radius

For example:

```
/testfor @a[x=64,y=10,z=64,r=5]
```

(Search for players on coordinates 64,64 at height 10, with a radius of 5 blocks)

### Variables

Specify the location:

- **@p**   nearest player
- **@r**   random player
- **@a**   all players
- **@e**   all entities

Specify the values:

- **x**, **y**, **z**  coordinate
- **r**, **rm**    radius (max, min)
- **m**    game mode
- **c**    count
- **l**, **lm**    experience level (max, min)
- **score_name**   max score
- **score_name_min**   min score
- **team** team name
- **name** entity name
- **dx**, **dy**, **dz**   volume dimensions
- **rx**, **rxm**  vertical rotation (max, min)
- **ry**, **rym**  horizontal rotation (max, min)
- **type** entity type

### Examples:

To test if Alice is online:

```
testfor Alice
```

To count the number of players in survival mode within a 3-block radius of (0,64,0):

```
testfor @a[0,64,0,3,m=0]
```

To count the number of players currently flying:

```
testfor @a {abilities:{flying:1b}}
```

To count the number of zombies within a 20-block radius of (0,64,0):

```
testfor @e[0,64,0,20,type=Zombie]
```

Source: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/198417/153355