# How do you use /testfor to test for players at specific coordinates?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

How do you use the `/testfor` command to test for players at specific coordinates? I've seen [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/198385/how-do-i-test-for-a-player-at-specific-coordinates#) but it doesn't work in PE. So far I have `/testfor @a[x=X, y=Y, z=Z]` but that acts like `@a` and ignores the `[x=X, y=Y, z=Z]` part. `X`, `Y` and `Z` are actual coordinates. Is this possible in PE?

I am playing Pocket Edition 1.1.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the specify a radius using "r". The coordinates just tell it from where to look, not the area in which it should look.

Comment: I only want it to look on that block. Would that be `r=1`?

Comment: Yes, that should work.

Comment: @cherryblossom Did this answer your question? If yes, please mark it as accepted so that this question doesn't remain open.