# Minecraft Command block /testfor with delta coordinates not working

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

So I'm trying to make a spleef and I found out about the testfor Command. I've been trying to make it run specific dimensions but it's not working.

I put in the Command `/testfor @p[x=-36,y=15,z=150,dx=16,dy=0,dz=-17]`.

(Second cords are `x=-20` `y=15` `z=133`)

But it just keeps on finding me even when I'm out of the allocated area, anyone know why?

Comment: "So I'm trying to make a spleef and I found out about the testfor Command." That already rings alarm bells in my head. You should first learn basic commands and then try to do big projects. Otherwise you will run into all kinds of problems either now or (even worse) later on. About your question: Where were you standing when the command targeted you? And did the command run on a clock or did you in some way activate it manually from a distance? Is the timestamp in the output the one that you expected?

Comment: I asked this question https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/314673/how-do-you-use-testfor-to-test-for-players-at-specific-coordinates about the `/testfor` command. I don't think `dx`, `dy` and `dz` are available in PE.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/314675/188492) answer says that `dx`, `dy` and `dz` are not available in PE yet. It will just ignore those parameters. You could use `r` instead but it would be a spherical area.